# Split a column in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sorry if I can't explain properly the issue I'm facing since I don't really understand it that much. I'm starting to learn Python and to practice I try to do projects that I face in my day to day job, but using Python. Right now I'm stuck with a project and would like some help or guidance, I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Index  Country   Name    IDs
0      USA       John    PERSID|12345
                         SSO|John123
                         STARTDATE|20210101
                         WAVE|WAVE39
--------------------------------------------
1      UK        Jane    PERSID|25478
                         SSO|Jane123
                         STARTDATE|20210101
                         WAVE|WAVE40
```

(I apologize since I can't create a table on this post since the separator of the ids is a | ) but you get the idea, every person has 4 IDs and they are all on the same "cell" of the dataframe, each ID separated from its value by pipes, I need to split those ID's from their values, and put them on separate columns so I get something like this

| index | Country | Name | PERSID | SSO | STARTDATE | WAVE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | USA | John | 12345 | John123 | 20210101 | WAVE39 |
| 1 | UK | Jane | 25478 | Jane123 | 20210101 | WAVE40 |

Now, adding to the complexity of the table itself, I have another issues, for example, the order of the ID's won't be the same for everyone and some of them will be missing some of the ID's.
I honestly have no idea where to begin, the first thing I thought about trying was to split the IDs column by spaces and then split the result of that by pipes, to create a dictionary, convert it to a dataframe and then join it to my original dataframe using the index.

But as I said, my knowledge in python is quite pathetic, so that failed catastrophically, I only got to the first step of that plan with a `Client_ids = df.IDs.str.split()`, that returns a series with the IDs separated one from each other like `['PERSID|12345', 'SSO|John123', 'STARTDATE|20210101', 'WAVE|Wave39']` but I can't find a way to split it again because I keep getting an error saying the the list object doesn't have attribute 'split'

How should I approach this? what alternatives do I have to do it?

Thank you in advance for any help or recommendation

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options to consider to do this. Here's how I would do it.

I will split the values in `IDs` by `\n` and `|`. Then create a dictionary with key:value for each split of values of `|`. Then join it back to the dataframe and drop the `IDs` and `temp` columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
["USA", "John","""PERSID|12345
SSO|John123
STARTDATE|20210101
WAVE|WAVE39"""],

["UK", "Jane", """PERSID|25478
SSO|Jane123
STARTDATE|20210101
WAVE|WAVE40"""],

["CA", "Jill", """PERSID|12345
STARTDATE|20210201
WAVE|WAVE41"""]], columns=['Country', 'Name', 'IDs'])

    
df['temp'] = df['IDs'].str.split('\n|\|').apply(lambda x: {k:v for k,v in zip(x[::2],x[1::2])})

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['temp'].values.tolist(), df.index))
df = df.drop(columns=['IDs','temp'],axis=1)

print (df)
```

With this approach, it does not matter if a row of data is missing. It will sort itself out.

The output of this will be:

Original DataFrame:

```
   Country       Name    IDs
0      USA       John    PERSID|12345
                         SSO|John123
                         STARTDATE|20210101
                         WAVE|WAVE39
1      UK        Jane    PERSID|25478
                         SSO|Jane123
                         STARTDATE|20210101
                         WAVE|WAVE40
2      CA        Jill    PERSID|12345
                         STARTDATE|20210201
                         WAVE|WAVE41
```

Updated DataFrame:

```
  Country  Name PERSID      SSO STARTDATE    WAVE
0     USA  John  12345  John123  20210101  WAVE39
1      UK  Jane  25478  Jane123  20210101  WAVE40
2      CA  Jill  12345      NaN  20210201  WAVE41
```

Note that Jill did not have a SSO value. It set the value to `NaN` by default.

Comment: I love this answer.  Keep in mind that `join` joins on `index` and the behavior in your answer works because the OPs index happened to match a default index `[0, 1, 2]`.  Instead, use the `df.index` in the `DataFrame` constructor.  `df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['temp'].values.tolist(), df.index))`

Comment: Thank You @piRSquared. Yes, agree with you. Updated the answer

Comment: Hey @JoeFerndz thank you for your answer, I like that idea and that's the logic I had in my mind even though I had no idea of how to actually do it. but trying this solution i keep getting a `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable` when doing the split step. Any idea what could be the reason? or how to troubleshoot it? I'm really new to python so debugging is still confusing. Thank you so much

Comment: @Jhilbran, did you have any data changes? I am not able to see where you may get 'float' error. The only place it can is if a value is NAN. What value in your row is NAN?

Comment: @JoeFerndz there's some rows that have no data whatsoever for the ID's, so they show as nan. Part of the project is to find out who those people are during the audit, as well how many of the IDs they are missing so they can be corrected

Answer (score 0):

First generate your dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["USA", "John","""PERSID|12345
SSO|John123
STARTDATE|20210101
WAVE|WAVE39"""],
["UK", "Jane", """
PERSID|25478
SSO|Jane123
STARTDATE|20210101
WAVE|WAVE40"""]], columns=['Country', 'Name', 'IDs'])
```

Then split the last cell using lambda

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(df.apply(lambda r: {p:q for p,q in [x.split("|") for x in r.IDs.split()]}, axis=1).values))
```

Lastly concat the dataframes together.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution

```
remove_word = ["PERSID", "SSO" ,"STARTDATE" ,"WAVE"]
for i ,col in enumerate(remove_word):
  df[col] = df.IDs.str.replace('|'.join(remove_word), '', regex=True).str.split("|").str[i+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use regex named capture groups with `pd.String.str.extract`

```
def ng(x):
    return f'(?:{x}\|(?P<{x}>[^\n]+))?\n?'

fields = ['PERSID', 'SSO', 'STARTDATE', 'WAVE']

pat = ''.join(map(ng, fields))

df.drop('IDs', axis=1).join(df['IDs'].str.extract(pat))

  Country  Name PERSID      SSO STARTDATE    WAVE
0     USA  John  12345  John123  20210101  WAVE39
1      UK  Jane  25478  Jane123  20210101  WAVE40
2      CA  Jill  12345      NaN  20210201  WAVE41
```

---

#### Setup

Credit to @JoeFerndz for sample `df`.
**NOTE**: this sample has missing values in some `'IDs'`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
["USA", "John","""PERSID|12345
SSO|John123
STARTDATE|20210101
WAVE|WAVE39"""],

["UK", "Jane", """PERSID|25478
SSO|Jane123
STARTDATE|20210101
WAVE|WAVE40"""],

["CA", "Jill", """PERSID|12345
STARTDATE|20210201
WAVE|WAVE41"""]], columns=['Country', 'Name', 'IDs'])
```